# use to_date oracle function using week number and day number oracle

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to get a date from day of the week number and week of the month number.

For example, I have a table called `Club` that stores on which day and week are exams available, it has `dayOfExam` and `weekOfExam` attributes.

```
dayOfExam=2 (Monday).   
weekOfExam=1
```

That means exams are available on every Monday of the first week of each month. And I need `04-JAN-2016 ... 08-FEB-2016 .. 07-MAR-16 and so on....`

I tried using like

```
TO_DATE('21012016','DWMMYYYY');
```

Is it possible to get that date? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, you can just use `next_day` and add a multiple of 7 days.  If you want to return the date for each month in the year, you can do something like this.  If you want more months, you can adjust the starting date and the number of months to go forward.

```
with x as (
  select 2 dayOfExam, 1 weekOfExam from dual
),
first_of_month as (
  select add_months( date '2016-01-01', level-1 ) mnth,
         dayOfExam,
         weekOfExam
    from x
 connect by level <= 12
)
select next_day( mnth, dayOfExam ) + 7 * (weekOfExam - 1) the_date
  from first_of_month;
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked... but instead of giving  date '2016-01-01' in add_months i would like to assign any date.. for example if the exams are programmed only until november and i want to schedule a new one in december i want to check the last exam date (in this case '07-NOV-16') and from that date, create the december date (it's gonna be 05-dic-16 anyway like from the beginning but i can´t use always first day of the month)

Comment: @GonzaloMachado - I'm not sure that I understand your question.  You can obviously change the query in the `first_of_month` CTE.  If you want to do `select add_months( trunc(date '2016-11-07', 'MM'), 1 ) mnth from dual` you'd get the date of the next month.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't work for every day/week number.... if i use day 2 (Monday) and week 4 its returning the wrong date, with 7 days more.. i thought that it was for the +7 but not for every case.... what i was trying to explain above is that i have 2 cases... if there is not any scheduled exam i can use that code, and calculate the next day from the first of every month... but if it exist a previous exam (on the 2nd day of the first week of november) 07-nov-16 i need to calculate the next date from that and its 05-dic-16

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a simpler way to do this, but i wrote two options.

If you want the n-th ocurrence of given week day in the month you can use this code:

```
declare
    l_month_year char(6):= '012016'; -- JAN-2016
    l_date date;
begin
    with base as (
        select to_date(ltrim(to_char(level, '00'))||l_month_year, 'ddmmyyyy') examdate,
            to_char(to_date(ltrim(to_char(level, '00'))||l_month_year, 'ddmmyyyy'), 'd') dayofweek,
            count(*) over(partition by to_char(to_date(ltrim(to_char(level, '00'))||l_month_year, 'ddmmyyyy'), 'd') order by level rows between unbounded preceding and current row) ocurrence
        from dual
        connect by level <= to_number(to_char(last_day(to_date(l_month_year, 'mmyyyy')), 'dd'))
    )    
    select examdate
      into l_date 
      from base
     where ocurrence = 1 and dayofweek = 2;

    Dbms_Output.put_line(to_char(l_date, 'dd-MON-yyyy'));  
end;
```

If you want the date in given week day of n-th week of month, that's the code:

```
declare
    l_month_year char(6):= '012016'; -- JAN-2016
    l_date date;
begin
    with base as (
        select to_date(ltrim(to_char(level, '00'))||l_month_year, 'ddmmyyyy') examdate,
            to_char(to_date(ltrim(to_char(level, '00'))||l_month_year, 'ddmmyyyy'), 'd') dayofweek,
            to_char(to_date(ltrim(to_char(level, '00'))||l_month_year, 'ddmmyyyy'), 'ww') - min(to_char(to_date(ltrim(to_char(level, '00'))||l_month_year, 'ddmmyyyy'), 'ww')) over() + 1 weekofmonth 
        from dual
        connect by level <= to_number(to_char(last_day(to_date(l_month_year, 'mmyyyy')), 'dd'))
    )    
    select examdate
      into l_date 
      from base
     where weekofmonth = 1 and dayofweek = 2;

    Dbms_Output.put_line(to_char(l_date, 'dd-MON-yyyy'));  
exception when no_data_found then
    Dbms_Output.put_line('there is not a day 2 in week 1 of '||to_char(to_date(l_month_year, 'mmyyyy'), 'Month-YYYY'));
end;
```

Note that for February-2016 in first case "01-FEV-2016" is outputted, because it's the Monday of the first week. In the second way, the output is "08-FEV-2016": the second occurrence of Monday in February.